# Using htmlspecialchars on href

Tags: php, html

To protect my site from XSS, I am using `htmlspecialchars` on an href like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($usersLink, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">User&#039;s Link</a>
```

Is there anything wrong with this practice?
Is it possible that it might deform or invalidate the link?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` with `ENT_QUOTES` and a character encoding defined ought to be _safe,_ but for URLS specifically, I'd advise using `urlencode` instead: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php